# Copia da Mensagem de Boas Vindas - Magento 1.7

Tags: magento

Alguém saberia me dizer como faço para receber uma cópia da mensagem de boas vindas (Aquela com e-mail e senha) de cada novo cliente da minha loja?
Eu acho que talvez seja aqui "Customer account form block" mas não sei como fazer para vir uma cópia para mim.

Obrigado!!

Comment: Guardar as senhas de maneira legível no banco de dados já não é recomendado. Receber as senhas de todos os seus clientes por email seria, no mínimo, antiético.

Comment: Entendo seu ponto de vista, mas eu realmente preciso disso, você saberia como fazer?

Comment: Não sei, nunca usei o magento.

Comment: @bfavaretto no mínimo .... isso vai dar um rolo muito grande .... também é bom informar a loja assim não compraremos la com "tanta" segurança

Answer (score 1):

Não tem essa opção pelo painel administrativo do Magento, acredito que você conseguiria o que quer tendo que alterar o método **sendNewAccountEmail** da classe **app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php**